# Getting error in if condition in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am getting error "Unexpected error near fi". Please find below my code. I am trying to run in from mac terminal.

```
DIRECTORY="/Users/<user_name>/a"
DESTINATION_FOLDER="/Users/<user_name>/Public/Deploy"

if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ];
then
  rm -rf "$DIRECTORY";
fi
```

Comment: I'm just wondering... what is your shell? `echo $SHELL`

Comment: And if you run your script like this: `sh script.sh` ?

Answer (score 0):

There should be either a new line or a semicolon before `fi`:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ] ; then rm -rf "$DIRECTORY" ; fi
```

Comment: Also, there should be spaces inside your condition: [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]

Comment: I am still getting same error, after incorporating both suggestions